# Why is the reaction rate of tert-butyl chloride solvolysis faster in 80% water/20% acetone, than in 70% water/30% acetone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stability, nucleophilicity

The solvent is polar protic, so the mechanism is SN1. However, I don't understand how the composition of water and acetone in the solvent affects the reaction rate.

Answer (score 3):

Water is more polar than acetone, so 80/20 water/acetone is a more polar solvent than 70/30 water/acetone.  Since the SN1 reaction has a positively charged carbocation intermediate, more polar solvents are better able to solvate and stabilize this intermediate.  That is why more water leads to faster reaction.

The relationship between solvent polarity and *t*-butyl chloride hydrolysis rates was investigated in [1948 by Grunwald and Winstein](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01182a117).  They looked at acetone/water as a solvent system, and also ethanol/water.  Here's a small portion of their data:

[image]

They were interested in describing the solvent dependence through the equation $$\log{\frac{k}{k_0}}=m Y$$, where:

- $Y$ is a solvent-dependent, substrate-*in*dependent parameter, with 80/20 ethanol/water chosen as the "reference" solvent for which $Y=0$.  This parameter describes the "ionizing power" of the solvent.
- $m$ is a solvent-*in*dependent, substrate-dependent parameter, with t-butyl chloride chosen as a "reference" substrate where $m=1$.
- $k_0$ is the reaction rate of the reference substrate (which is *t*-butyl chloride, conveniently for the purposes of your question) in the references solvent (80% ethanol in water).
- $k$ is the reaction rate in an arbitrary solvent with a $Y$ parameter of $Y$ of an arbitrary substrate with an $m$ parameter of $m$.

You can see from their data that the table I've excerpted that their data is qualitatively consistent with their equation.  Additional parts of their paper show a good quantitative fit too, for many (but not all) substrates and solvent systems.

It's worthwhile noting how strong the effect is.  Having 10% water improves rates by more than 10-fold relative to absolute ethanol.  And going up to 30% water improves rates by almost another 10-fold.  The bottom two entries are for acetone as the solvent.  There is almost a 10,000-fold difference in rates between 5% acetone and 80% acetone.

Later in 2007, [Peters exhaustively reviewed](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/cr068021k) solvent participation in SN1 reactions and mentioned there has been pushback against the simple Winstein/Grunwald mode, saying:

> As of 2007, it is clear that there is no general consensus
> as to the process by which the solvent participates in the
> solvolysis of tert-butyl chloride. To borrow a recent statement
> from Richard, “...the impression that studies of solvolysis at
> tertiary carbon have resulted in a morass of experimental
> data and which, when interpreted individually, provide
> support for conflicting mechanistic conclusions” captures the
> general sentiment of the field.

So "why" the reaction is faster with more water around is a hard question to answer precisely, but I don't think there is any doubt that more polar solvents will result in faster rates.  Unless you are reaching for world-class expertise and exacting quantitative accuracy, the simple Winstein/Grunwald model that more polar solvents have more "ionizing power" to stabilize the carbocation intermediates is probably a good place to start.